# Python unhashable type: QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, qtreewidgetitem

I'd like to reverse my key and value in a `dict`. Item numbers are created as `QTreeWidgetItem`, and `dataBlock#`s are the data object for the item number.

```
my_dict = { dataBlock1:item1, dataBlock2:item2, dataBlock3:item3}

inv_dict = {v:k for k,v in my_dict.items()}
```

I got the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'QTreeWidgetItem'
```

How do I reverse the key & value in this case. I need item numbers as keys in the `inv_dict` for another use purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Since items are unhashable, one solution is that store each item in a list and use its index as the value in `my_dict`. Now you have integers as values and you can reverse the key values.
Another way that I'm not sure about that, you can implement `__hash__` function for your item's class.